# Integrate the exponential of sum of circular differences?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Given positive integer $N$ and parameters $T>0$, $a$, $b$, what is

$\int_{t_1=0}^T \cdots \int_{t_N=0}^T e^{a(t_1+\cdots+t_N)+b(|t_1-t_2|+\cdots+|t_{i-1}-t_i|+|t_N-t_1|)} dt_1 \cdots dt_N$ ?

Any thought will be very much appreciated!

Comment: It's easy if we have $t_i\leq t_j~~\forall i<j$